# What happened to Apple's sample code for writing a Stickies app?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I don't remember if it shipped with Xcode, or if I downloaded it from developer.apple.com, but there used to be sample code available to create a Stickies-style app in Xcode.  It was probably in Objective-C, since it was several years ago that I remember seeing it.

It might very well have been the same code Apple uses for their own Stickies app.

Where can I find it?  (Preferably in Swift, but probably in Objective-C.)

I've Googled, DuckDuckGo'ed, etc.  I've [searched on https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2022/), all finding nothing.

[image: example of sticky notes]

Comment: are you looking for stay on top functionality?

Comment: No, I have ideas for solving the problems of Sticky Note apps, but I'd rather not have to recreate all the unoriginal features if I can just use what Apple made freely available, before adding my own original features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SyncServices_SimpleStickies/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009051

There is also this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SyncServices_StickiesWithCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009052

This is what I googled: **apple sample code old**

Which got me here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/

And searching for sample code called stickies got me to it.